# I am getting this following GPG error. please provide the solution

Tags: apt, nvidia, updates, gnupg

By executing `sudo apt-get update` command I'm getting following error:

```
W: GPG error: http://nvdebmirror.nvidia.com/ubuntu precise InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: 32E5546BC5A41548F39DD8B8BA79F56D5BA3076A.
```

I use ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Hello, please provide more information, eg.: what you are taring to do; which command generates this error message; which is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: "Precise" suggests this is a 12.04 package...is no longer supported.

Comment: "i am using ubuntu 18.04" then why do you use precise in the command? Please fix your command.

Comment: I would STRONGLY suggest you disable the nvdebmirror on your system.  Precise is ancient and obsolete and no longer supported so it should not be getting repository updates anyways by nVidia.  Remove that source from your apt lists.